# Mathematica 9 link in OriginLab

Tags: export

Hi (I am an absolute newbie), I need to send Mathematica data to the program OriginLab to plot and change the graphs.

Does anyone know if it is possible to send data from Mathematica 9 via Mathematica link to OriginLab?

I have tried, but it was only possible to send data from OriginLab to the Kernel and use the programming power of Mathematica 9 to receive the results back in OriginLab.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to transfer? Would a plain CSV style file output do? According to their website it can import that. And why not plotting in Mathematica itself?

Comment: The raw data of a diagramm or the diagramm itself I want to transfer. I dont want to save my data in Mathematica and import it again in OriginLab (is also a solution but not the nice way), there exists a directly Mathematica link to Origin which I tried to use. I hoped that someone could tell me if it is possible with Mathematica 9 or if the transfer is only possible in one direction from OriginLab to Mathematica and back to Origin.

Comment: If you don't want to work over the Mathematica link from the OriginLab side (why?) you could follow the COM route. [Mathematica can work with COM objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/ref/LoadCOMTypeLibrary.html) and OriginLab apparently [can act as a COM server](http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Origin-As-AutoServer-APP). I note that working with COM is rather complex and not for the faint of heart.